# How many different bets can you place if there are n matches?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose there are n matches (so 2*n different teams) and you can only bet the winner, but you can make single bets, double bets, triple bets, etc... How many different bets can you make?

For example for n = 2 (two matches):
Team A against team B
Team C against team D
There are 8 possible bets:
A, B, C, D, AC, AD, BC, BD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you think of your choices for each game, you can either, bet on the first team, bet on the second team, or bet on no teams. That is 3 choices, if we have $n$ different games then we have a sequence of $3^n$ permutations of choices we can make, but you need to subtract the case where you make no bets, so subtract $1$.
$$3^n-1$$